# How to use plugin in wishlist?

Tags: magento2, wishlist, plugin

I tried,

**app/code/Test/WishlistPlugin/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
<type name="\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist">
    <plugin name="WishlistPluginModelWishlist" type="Test\WishlistPlugin\Model\Wishlist" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Test/WishlistPlugin/Model/Wishlist.php**

```
namespace Test\WishlistPlugin\Model;

class Wishlist
{    
   public function beforeAddCatalogProduct(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $product, $qty = 0, $forciblySetQty = false)
  { 
    return $qty;
  }
}
```

But function is not called in app/code/Test/WishlistPlugin/Model/Wishlist.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a **protected** method which magento plugin does not support for more details you can refer the **limitations** of plugins [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Further more I assume you want to updated product qty when adding product to wishlist you can do in such a way

Define your plugin in di.xml

```
<type name="\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist">
    <plugin name="WishlistPluginModelWishlist" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Wishlist"/>
</type>
```

Instead of using AddCatalogProduct protected method you can use addNewItem public method

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin;

class Wishlist
{    
   public function afterAddNewItem(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $subject, $product)
  { 
       // apply your logic here
       $product->setQty(2);
  }
}
```

**Updated**

```
class Wishlist
{    
    public function aroundAddNewItem(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $subject, \Closure $proceed, $product, $qty, $forciblySetQty = true)
    { 
        $result = $proceed($product, $qty, $forciblySetQty);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I have used  public method beforeAddNewItem. You are very close to my answer. Actually in function _addCatalogProduct, I dont want to update quantity. I want to override a function where I can comment these lines. 
$qty = $forciblySetQty ? $qty : $item->getQty() + $qty;
$item->setQty($qty)->save(); I want to prevent user from updating same product in wishlist.

Comment: you can give me any suggestion also?

Comment: You want that each time a product is added the qty should remain 1 ?

Comment: yes, it should remain 1

Comment: You can use the after method and set qty back to 1 or else try my updated answer for around method if it works for you.

Comment: its working perfectly. thank you so much. We cannot use before method?

Comment: I dont think so because if we try to set qty before it will be added in the original method after it is called.